# protocol buffers in web application architecture -- when are they not worth the trouble?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am new to web development, and I've seen many sites preaching the benefits of using protocol buffers -- for example: https://codeclimate.com/blog/choose-protocol-buffers/.

I'm not sure if some of the benefits apply to my use case:

1. **Having a unified schema out of the .proto file:** If I validate my data in the front and back-end, which I should do anyway, a unified schema is enforced explicitly. I don't see any added benefit in this regard from using protocol buffers.
2. **Auto generating the setters and getters from the .proto file:** This looks like a nice selling point. But, I wouldn't need any setters and getters if I don't use protocol buffers in the first place. I found them really cumbersome to work with:

   - They remove capitalization, which alters the original variable names
   - They are unnatural to work with. For example, in c++ I would want work with just a plain old data structure, but instead I have to do something like ptr_message->shouldBeStruct1().shouldBeStructArray(20).shouldBeInt();
3. **Easy Language Interoperability:**  I really doubt it is good practice to design my data consuming code so that it works for a protobuf message rather than a struct. So, I would need to parse the protobuf into a plain data struct first.

The only potential benefit I see is the reduced data size when transmitting on the wire. But, does this really justify the overhead of additional middleware to work with protocol buffers? What am I missing?

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: Basically getting the data from the browser and number crunching in the back end, which is node.js with a c++ addon